# Python Virtual Enviroment in Windows will not select the correct environment

Tags: python, windows, command-prompt, python-venv

We have created a virtual environment for Python in Windows 10 utilizing virtualenv tool loaded through pip.  We created the new environment and activated it with activate.bat.  Once activated, we installed a bunch of packages via pip for this environment.  The first time we did this is worked fine and went to the following folder when we checked with `which python`: `C:\Users\dxm435\Documents\new_model_accel\ma\Scripts`

However, when we closed out and went back in and reactivated the environment, it no longer takes us to that version and instead goes to the original one in the environment at `C:\Users\dxm435\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38`.  We've tried just about everything we can but it refuses to point back to the first directory.  The latest step we are trying is checking if something is wrong with the activate.bat.  Is there anything wrong with the activate.bat script?  We could reinstall the environment but there's nothing to say it won't  happen again.

```
@set "VIRTUAL_ENV=C:\Users\dxm435\Documents\new model accel\ma"

@if defined _OLD_VIRTUAL_PROMPT (
    @set "PROMPT=%_OLD_VIRTUAL_PROMPT%"
) else (
    @if not defined PROMPT (
        @set "PROMPT=$P$G"
    )
    @if not defined VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT (
        @set "_OLD_VIRTUAL_PROMPT=%PROMPT%"
    )
)
@if not defined VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT (
    @if "" NEQ "" (
        @set "PROMPT=() %PROMPT%"
    ) else (
        @for %%d in ("%VIRTUAL_ENV%") do @set "PROMPT=(%%~nxd) %PROMPT%"
    )
)

@REM Don't use () to avoid problems with them in %PATH%
@if defined _OLD_VIRTUAL_PYTHONHOME @goto ENDIFVHOME
    @set "_OLD_VIRTUAL_PYTHONHOME=%PYTHONHOME%"
:ENDIFVHOME

@set PYTHONHOME=

@REM if defined _OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH (
@if not defined _OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH @goto ENDIFVPATH1
    @set "PATH=%_OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH%"
:ENDIFVPATH1
@REM ) else (
@if defined _OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH @goto ENDIFVPATH2
    @set "_OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH=%PATH%"
:ENDIFVPATH2

::@set "PATH=%VIRTUAL_ENV%\Scripts;%PATH%"
```